# Limit width/height jquery container

Tags: jquery, height, limit

I have the following code does is take the high benchmark of your browser window.

My question is if I can run to condition apartir only true width of the main web container (eg div # container 980px).

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var ventana = $(window).height();
    var altura = ventana / 2;
    $("#gallery").css('height', altura);
});
```

Regards

Comment: "if I can run to condition apartir only true width" What does that mean? Your code looks like it would work.

Comment: yeah that's my code I want to work from 980px wide site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `if( $( window ).width() > x )` to only enable the resize effect for specific window widths:

```
var window = $( window );
window.resize( function() {
    if( window.width() > 980 )
    {
        var ventana = window.height();
        $( '#gallery' ).css( 'height', ventana / 2 );
    }
    else
    {
        /* reset for browsers that fire the event only once
         * at the end of the window resize action */
        $( '#gallery' ).css( 'height', 'auto' );
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thanks you :) es justo que lo necesitaba

Comment: @Raul please speak English only on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you are asking for the browser window's height with this line

```
var ventana = $(window).height();
```

Change it to

```
var ventana = $("#container").height();
```

To get your site's height. But you probably want the width, so you should call `width()` instead. If what you're asking is to only run the code when your actual site resizes (I don't speak spanish but I think I understand your question), you use:

```
$("#container").resize(function(){
    //code
});
```

Of course, this will not work when you set a fixed width.